# Python Pandas - Getting dates for UK FY, as well as start date and end date of previous month

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a script that will search our databases for data, mung it, and then present it.

To do this, I need to create 5 variables.

When it runs, it needs to find the first date of the previous month, the end date of the previous month. It also needs to find the first date of the current FY (01/04/**), the end date of the previous FY and the start date of the previous FY.

I am having difficulties doing this. Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:  Worked out the first and last date of the previous month:

```
import datetime
today=datetime.date.today()
first = today.replace(day=1)
lastMonth = first - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
firstMonth = lastMonth.replace(day=1)
```

But still need to work out the FY data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer was pretty simple when I sat down and thought about it. I am posting my answer in case anyone comes across it:

```
import datetime
dt=datetime.datetime.now()

if dt.month>3:
    da=dt.year-1
    db=dt.year
    fy1="01/04/"+str(da)
    fy2="31/03/"+str(db)
else:
    da=dt.year-2
    db=dt.year-1
    fy1="01/04/"+str(da)
    fy2="31/03/"+str(db)
```

This is to get the previous financial year depending on if the current day is greater than March or not.